# Изменения "за чистоту русского языка"?

Tags: обсуждение, правки

Я новичок на SO, может я чего-то не понял, но мы ведь вроде здесь на вопросы по программированию отвечаем, а не изучаем русский язык?

Ладно бы, если бы это были просто опечатки или пропущенные знаки препинания, но изменения речевых оборотов, авторской стилистики, зачем?

Особенно активен в этом пользователь @Vladimir991

Comment: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/220/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите конкретные примеры - я, например, сто лет в очереди не залезал, они и без меня давно не превышают 20.

Comment: Если коротко: мы тут не на вопросы отвечаем, а собираем знания, чтобы они другим пригодились.

Comment: @Etki http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16900
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16901

Comment: Да, @@Vladimir991 перегибает местами. Ему уже писали про это. И вы не стесняйтесь писать корректору, если считаете, что ваш пост "слишком исправлен". Кроме того,  вы всегда можете откатить правку вашего поста.

Comment: Если авторская стилистика оставляет желать лучшего (например, то же _"Ковырялся с книжкой"_), то не вижу ничего плохого в том, чтобы улучшить пост, сделав стиль текста вопроса более похожим на официально-деловой. Vladimir991 часто перегибает в описании правки - да, есть такое. И мне это весьма не нравится, особенно учитывая, что он не всегда прав в плане правки.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Если автор просто поправил орфографические ошибки** — пускай остается как есть.

**Если вы считаете, что автор исказил смысл вашего сообщения** — делайте откат. Жмите вот на такую надпись под вопросом или ответом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом выбирайте последнюю версию перед нежелательной правкой и жмите `откат`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Если искажение явно вредоносное, или повторяется неоднократно** - можете нажать `тревога` — `требуется вмешательство модератора` и объяснить модератору суть проблемы.

**Пример**: здесь откатили текст, после чего модератор заблокировал текст на пару дней от редактирования. Спорные правки 4..6 заключались в переводе части текста на английский.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/432617/revisions