# Какую метку использовать для вопросов, связанных с русским языком в качестве языка для общения на ruSO?

Tags: обсуждение, создание-метки

Есть метка [русский-язык](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba), но она про другую площадку. Какую метку стоит использовать непосредственно для ruSO и Meta ruSO, касательно вопросов про русский язык, используемый **для общения** между участниками и не касающихся перевода или внешнего вида ruSO?

Примеры вопросов:

- [Местоимения. Пока не про нас, но хочется уточнить](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9603/)
- [Причины, по которым необходимо переименовать "Нормы поведения" в "Соглашение о поведении" или в "Правила поведения"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9590)
- [Здесь предпочтение отдаём словам на русском языке или, превозмогая трудности, используем иностранные слова, написанные русскими буквами?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9508/)
- [Изменения "за чистоту русского языка"?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/630/)
- [Не тот язык пять раз проверь?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5509/)
- [Сколько сайтов по русскому есть на Stackoverflow?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/744/)
- [Язык меток: русский или английский (особенно в случае составных меток)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9363/)
- [Допустимость вопросов на транслите](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8410/)

и т.п.

Comment: Эм.. Это всё те же попытки переименовать [meta-tag:локализация]?

Comment: @Qwertiy нет, про язык, используемый для общения. Ваша метка совсем про другое.

Comment: Какую хотите, такую и создавайте. Главное, чтобы остальные хотя бы смутно догадались, о чем речь в топике пойдет

Comment: @avp хотел "русский язык", но её уже заняли, на мой взгляд зря.

Comment: @edem, тогда попробуйте `"родная речь"`

Comment: Что-то тут половина вопросов вообще ничего общего с описанным не имеют.

Comment: @avp неплохо, но не для всех он родной.

Comment: @Qwertiy оставьте нужную половину, если вы поняли вопрос.

Comment: В интернетах подобное обычно тагают как `grammar-nazi`.

Comment: @Kyubey вы здесь находите присутствие "grammatics" как основы для этих вопросов?)

Comment: @edem, нет, он про это: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qj7ww.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По метке [русский язык](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA) сейчас имеется три вопроса.

Два из них не относятся к сайту «Русский язык»:

- [IT-"жаргон", околокомпьютерный диалект](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2903/it-%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bd-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d1%8c%d1%8e%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82)
- [Нужна ли защитная политика по отношению к англицизмам?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2584/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%ba-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bc)

По сути к «братскому» сайту относится только один вопрос: [О проблемах сайта Русский язык](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1394/%d0%9e-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%a0%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba)

Считаю, что не стоит тратить целую метку для одного этого вопроса. Попробуйте предложить изменение описания метки. После этого можно будет поправить вопросы.

В дальнейшем, если появятся другие вопросы по «дружественному» подсайту, то для них можно будет завести отдельную метку, нечто вроде «русский-язык-stackexchange»

Comment: Для вопросов про сайты сети есть метка [meta-tag:stackexchange].

Comment: @Suvitruf т.е. вы разделяете мнение по изменению описания метки "русский-язык"?

Comment: @edem в целом да. Но лучше, думаю, отдельный вопрос-опрос сделать с ссылкой на это обсуждение.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял суть вопроса, то меткой может быть [чистота-речи](/questions/tagged/%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8) или [чистота-языка](/questions/tagged/%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0).

Но под неё из перечисленных подпадают вопросы:

- [Здесь предпочтение отдаём словам на русском языке или, превозмогая трудности, используем иностранные слова, написанные русскими буквами?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9508/)
- [Изменения "за чистоту русского языка"?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/630/)
- [Язык меток: русский или английский (особенно в случае составных меток)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9363/)
- [Допустимость вопросов на транслите](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8410/)

и ещё (хотя тут вполне хватает [локализация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f)):

- [Причины, по которым необходимо переименовать "Нормы поведения" в "Соглашение о поведении" или в "Правила поведения"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9590)

И совершенно не подпадают:

- [Местоимения. Пока не про нас, но можно побрыкаться?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9603/)
- [Не тот язык пять раз проверь?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5509/)
- [Сколько сайтов по русскому есть на Stackoverflow?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/744/)

Comment: Даже не сколько чистота, сколько смысловое наполнение языка. Осталось придумать слово(сочетание).

Answer (score 1):

Я тут внезапно на главной обнаружил вопрос с меткой [стиль](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c) и очень похоже, что ты ищешь именно её?

Comment: Ух, чего только не найдёшь на Meta. Почитаю подробнее, но в целом, при беглом осмотре, я бы их объединил с "искомой", ибо вами упомянутая метка слишком узконаправленная, на мой взгляд.

Comment: @edem, на мой взгляд "стиль" - настолько широкое понятие, что я даже не представляю,как его тут можно назвать слишком узконаправленным... Впрочем, это не делает его прям удачным кандидатом.